# Why a URL with a query is always slower than that without a query?

Tags: query, cache, performance

I find a strange thing. For a WordPress site, a URL with a query is always slower than that without a query, even no Cache plugin is installed/enabled and no CDN cache is enabled. For example:

http://www.example.com/?mytest=yes

will always slower than

http://www.example.com/

Below are some of my test:

1. WP Fastest Cache disabled, URL with a query https://www.fastorslow.com/app/profile/3e875ed3-d45f-54fb-93a2-17466eeb8b79 is slower than the one without a query https://www.fastorslow.com/app/profile/7ef6f16f-6b0c-5ab6-9f1e-87c0c1a6a1aa
2. With WP Rocket enabled, https://www.fastorslow.com/app/profile/af27e983-1a38-5870-98a3-6cc19825aee1 is slower than https://www.fastorslow.com/app/profile/86d36215-0caf-51d7-b690-d3126a081376
3. Another server, https://www.fastorslow.com/app/profile/9273fb55-adfc-5b8c-aa93-687bc128a95d is slower than https://www.fastorslow.com/app/profile/51062160-fb20-5b0b-97ba-4ce428ba264c

Why?

Comment: I don't know, and in my case (no caching), fastorslow.com returned 94 when the query (`?mytest=yes`) was *not* present, and 98 when it's present. So you could try deactivating all plugins and switch to a default theme, then see if fastorslow.com still gives the same results.

Comment: it is like asking why page A is slower than page B. No one can tell you the answer for that as the kind of processing required might be different for two different URLs. At no place it is defind that A?key=1 is equal to A, those are two different URLs, they might have the same HTML result but no one promises that to be the general case therefor some different processing is most likely required.

Answer (score 0):

When you run a search (you call it a query) WordPress must use its DBMS (MariaDB / MySQL) to examine the entire text of every post, page, and user on your site. That takes time. There are some plugins out there to make search more efficient, but it is still work for your site to do.

I like the Relevanssi plugin for improving search.